# GraphDistance gives incorrect result in weighted multigraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 12.0**

 Multigraph support was introduced in 10.0

---

`GraphDistance` and `GraphDistanceMatrix` return incorrect results for the following weighted multigraphs. Is there a workaround?

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 1, 2 <-> 3}, 
   EdgeWeight -> {3, 3, 2, 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

[image]

There are two edges between vertices `1` and `2`. One of these edges has weight 3, the other weight 2.

The shortest path length between `1` and `2` is calculated as:

```
{GraphDistance[g, 1, 2], GraphDistance[g, 2, 1]}

(* {3., 5.} *)
```

```
GraphDistanceMatrix[g] // MatrixForm

|0.  3.  3.|
|5.  0.  1.|
|5.  1.  0.|
```

The shortest distance between 1 and 2 is not the same as the shortest distance between 2 and 1. Also, the distance matrix is not symmetric. Finally, neither 3, nor 5 is a correct result here. It should be 2.

**Is there a workaround for computing shortest paths in weighted multigraphs?**

---

Finally, edge weights are displayed incorrectly in the following:

```
SetProperty[g, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image]

Comment: Do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your observed behavior has already been confirmed by other users.

Comment: If you're sure those are bugs, please go on and report them to WRI. Otherwise,  please ask an answerable question. This site isn't a bug reporting tool ;)

Comment: If you want this fixed, please report it to Wolfram. This website is not affiliated with Wolfram.  They might not notice that you complained about this here.  This website is not for complaints, it's for questions.  If they do notice, and they do create a bug report, it might not receive the same weight as if you had reported it yourself.

Comment: I think this is directly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92014/issues-adding-properties-to-multigraph  I do think that multigraphs are near-unusable un Mathematica and should not have been introduced in this state.  It is in everyone's interest to have these bugs fixed.  But for that to happen, you need to talk to Wolfram. I voted to close this post because it is clearly not a question but a complaint and thus unsuitable for this site.  I suggest rephrasing it as a question to prevent closing.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I have already reported it to Wolfram, waiting for their reply.

Comment: I receive no reply from Wolfram. It seems that fixing this issue is difficult or currently they don't want to fix it.

Comment: You can use the `IGDistanceMatrix` function from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) as a workaround until this gets fixed.

Comment: @Purboo Did you get a CASE number from Wolfram? An automated response or similar?

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround is to use `IGDistanceMatrix` from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
IGDistanceMatrix[g]
(* {{0., 2., 3.}, {2., 0., 1.}, {3., 1., 0.}} *)
```

Another workaround is to convert the multi-graph to a simple graph and keep only the smallest weight for parallel edges.

Again IGraph/M has a function for this.

[image]

```
IGWeightedSimpleGraph[g, Min]
```

The distance matrix:

```
GraphDistanceMatrix@IGWeightedSimpleGraph[g, Min]
(* {{0., 2., 3.}, {2., 0., 1.}, {3., 1., 0.}} *)
```

Finally, we could do the same without IGraph/M, though the performance won't be nearly as good.

```
weightedSimpleEdges = 
 Min /@ GroupBy[
   Transpose@{Sort /@ EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]},
   First -> Last
 ]
(* <|1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 1|> *)

GraphDistanceMatrix@Graph[
  VertexList[g], 
  Keys[weightedSimpleEdges], 
  EdgeWeight -> Values[weightedSimpleEdges]
]
(* {{0., 2., 3.}, {2., 0., 1.}, {3., 1., 0.}} *)
```