# How to assign EdgeWeight to a multigraph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to make a program to illustrate the simplify process of a complex resistence network. I create a graph to represent the structure of the network and trying to use `EdgeWeight` to symbolize the value of resistence. but sometimes I'll need to deal with parallel resistence, so assigning `EdgeWeight` to them will be a problem.

In simple graphs, one can use:

```
gg=Graph[{1<->2,2<->3,3<->1},EdgeWeight->{1,2,3}]
```

to specify the weight of each edge. Then we can use `PropertyValue` to extract them:

```
PropertyValue[{gg,#},EdgeWeight]&/@EdgeList@gg
```

> {1,2,3}

But in a non-simple graph:

```
gg=Graph[{1<->2,1<->2,2<->3},EdgeWeight->{1,2,3}]
```

It seems that `EdgeWeight` simply ignored the weight assignment for parallel edges and consider all parallel edges to be the same:

```
PropertyValue[{gg, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ EdgeList@gg
```

> {1,1,3}

This put a great barrier on my programming, so how to solve this problem? How to allow multiple `EdgeWeight` assigned to parallel edges?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92014/issues-adding-properties-to-multigraph  Essentially, this can't possibly work properly with the current design of `Graph`.  I would consider this a bug.  If it is a problem for you, it would be good if you could report it to Wolfram Support. People have suggested it several times that the number of times an issue is reported is taken into account when Wolfram prioritizes it.  So please report it, even if Wolfram is aware of the problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, your comment prevent me from carrying my project on in time. :( not happy about that, but at least it ensures I won't make more frutile tries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want specifically, but can't you use symbolic `Edgeweight`s and have replace functions when using the weights?

Comment: @Feyre no, try the examples and you shall see. ;)

Comment: @Wjx I think you misunderstand what I mean. I mean to say that you let the `EdgeWeight` be, say, `r1`, and when you call the `Edgeweight`s, depending on how it is called let `r1` be replaced by either `1` or `2`.

Comment: @Feyre er, it will put a lot of restrictions on how you can manipulate the graph. in my real application, I'm not only create a graph, I add a lot of vertexes and lines. so it would be quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica's can't properly handle edge properties for multigraphs. The reason is that edges are typically referred to by their end vertices. Therefore there is no way to distinguish between multiple edges connecting the same vertices.

`EdgeWeight`, `EdgeCost`, and `EdgeCapacity` are the only edge properties which can even be *stored* for a multigraph.  These properties are stored as simple lists.  The `k`th element of the list corresponds to the `k`th edge.

Thus you *can* work with weighted multigraphs, but you must take care to only set or extract weights in a particular way.

You can extract weights as a vector like this:

```
wg = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3}, EdgeWeight -> {3, 4, 5}]

PropertyValue[wg, EdgeWeight]
(* {3, 4, 5} *)
```

Once these weights were set, you cannot easily change them.  `SetProperty[wg, EdgeWeight -> ...]` or `Graph[wg, EdgeWeight -> ...]` will produce incorrect results.

You can do this instead:

```
Graph[VertexList[wg], EdgeList[wg], EdgeWeight -> newWeights]
```

Whether it's worth the trouble, I do not know.  The risk of bumping into bugs is quite high.