# Can I label duplicate edges differently within adjacency graph?

Tags: labeling, graphs-and-networks

I want to label a duplicate edge I have with different labels in an adjacency graph.

So far I have this:

```
AdjacencyGraph[({
   {1, 1},
   {1, 2}
  }), VertexLabels -> {1 -> "v", 2 -> "u"}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 1) -> "δ", (1 -> 2) -> "γ", (2 -> 1) -> "β", (2 -> 2) -> "α"}]
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Is there a way to label one as `α_1` and `α_2`?

Comment: I don't think so. It's a problem with Graph's design. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92014/issues-adding-properties-to-multigraph

Answer (score 2):

```
ag = AdjacencyGraph[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> "v", 2 -> "u"}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 1) -> "δ", (1 -> 2) -> "γ", (2 -> 1) -> "β", (2 -> 2) -> "α"}];

Module[{i=1}, Show[ag] /. "α" :>Subscript["α", i++]]
```

[image]