# IncidentGraph not showing edge weights correctly

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am performing the following commands:

```
MI = 
  {{-1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {1,-1,1,0,0,0,0}, {0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0}, 
   {0,0,0,-1,-1,1,0}, {0,0,0,1,1,0,-1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1}};
Graf = 
  IncidenceGraph[MI, 
    EdgeWeight->{a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
    EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight",
    VertexLabels->"Name"];
Print[Graf];
```

The printed graph, `Graf`, does not show one edge with weight `e`. Instead, it shows the edge with repeated weight `d`. Does anybody know why? Sorry if it is an obvious question. I simply don't see what is wrong. Is this a bug in Mathematica?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12  Please see the discussion in the comments.  "Sorry if it is an obvious question." No, it's not obvious at all.

Comment: If you care about this issue, I strongly suggest you write to Wolfram Support and ask about it. There is little chance it will be fixed unless multiple different people bring it up. I have been complaining for years about this specific thing, but I am just one person.